# How can I query the encoding of a postgresql cluster?

Tags: postgresql, encoding

When you create a new postgresql cluster you can specify an encoding for the cluster, but I'm not sure to know how to retrieve it once the cluster has been created.

I have seen that with `\encoding` you can see an encoding, but I don't know it this is the encoding of the cluster or the encoding of the client.

I have also seen that with `\l` I can see the encoding used by each database.

And `SHOW server_encoding` shows another encoding.

What is the correct way to query for the value using during initialization?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each database in a cluster can have its own encoding, although this probably isn't useful for most people.

When you create the cluster, the encoding you specify is used for the template1 and postgres databases, so it is the default for all new ones. You can create a new database from template0 in a different encoding, though.

`\encoding` shows the encoding used for the client<->server communication protocol, and is equivalent to `show client_encoding`. `server_encoding` shows the encoding used for the database you are currently connected to. It should show the encoding used to create the cluster if you are connected to template1. The encoding for each database is listed in `pg_database`, e.g.:
should

```
select datname, pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) from pg_database
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use pg_controldata: `pg_controldata <path/to/cluster>  |grep LC_` where the path is where your cluster is located.

This will output something similar like this:

> LC_COLLATE:                               en_US.UTF-8
>
> LC_CTYPE:                                 en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Anyone have an explanation for the down vote?